Install ngx-joypixels to angular 14
To can we install deprecated package in Angular , i am using angular 14 in my application
package.json
"@angular/cdk": "^14.2.7",
"@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.0.0",

i want to add ngx-joypixels module to the project, its working fine with npm install --force only.
How can i fix this problem so that it can work with npm install  with out using force.

THe package is outdated, instead share the scenario you are trying to solve with this package, its not complicated, and you can solve that issue instead of trying to install an outdated package
